# How .htaccess works for public_html cpanel

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, cpanel, public-html

I have a Laravel project uploaded in root: `home/user/my-project-directory` and in `public_html` i have a directory some-directory-name. In this directory, I have a public Laravel directory.

The part that I don't understand is, where should I have a `.htaccess` file? In `public_html` directory or in every directory from `public_html`?

At this moment, when I go to www.mydomain.ro I get an index of `public_html` directory. After I select some-directory-name, I can access my website.

Why I'm asking this... If I have a `.htaccess` file in `public_html` and a `.htaccess` file in public_html/some-directory-name or if I don't have any one of them, the website still works the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The part that i don't understand is, where should i have a `.htaccess` file. In `public_html` directory or in every directory from `public_html`?

It depends what you are trying to achieve. But it is very common to have just one `.htaccess` file in the document root of your site. The `.htaccess` file in the document root can control the entire directory tree. The `.htaccess` file in the subdirectory overrides the parent `.htaccess` file and controls just that branch of the directory tree.

If you wanted to hide/rewrite the `some-directory-name` in the URL-path then you can't do this using only the `.htaccess` file in `some-directory-name` subdirectory, you would need to use the `.htaccess` file in the parent directory.

If you have a `.htaccess` file in every directory then it can get very messy and difficult to maintain. But there can be reasons to do this (but you don't have to).

You can also put the `.htaccess` file above the document root - but this may not do anything, depending on your server config.

> If i have a `.htaccess` file in `public_html` and a `.htaccess` file in `public_html/some-directory-name` or if i don't have any one of them, the website still works the same.

Then maybe you don't need a `.htaccess` file. However, how are you going to route "pretty" URLs through Laraval if you don't have a `.htaccess` file?

Incidentally, if you have access to the server config then you don't need to use `.htaccess` at all.

*Aside:* Why do you have a directory structure (public URL-path) of the form `/some-directory-name/public/`? Is that intentional?

---

**UPDATE:**

> What i'm trying to do is to access my website via `www.mydomain.ro`, not `www.mydomain.ro/some-dir-name`

In that case, you would need to use the `.htaccess` file in the document root to *internally rewrite* all requests to the `/some-dir-name` subdirectory. For example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^ /some-dir-name%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

You also need to make sure that all URLs in your project do not include the `/public-dir-name` URL-path.

This also renders all URLs outside the `/public-dir-name` directory inaccessible. If you specifically need to access these files then additional conditions can be added.

The condition that checks the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable is to ensure against a rewrite loop.

**UPDATE#2:** If you specifically need this to work for just one hostname, eg. `example.com` (and exclude all other hostnames / subdomains) then add an additional condition:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^ /some-dir-name%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

**UPDATE#3:** To make it work for a subdomain as well then you can modify the *CondPattern* to make the subdomain optional. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(subdomain\.)?example\.com [NC]
```

Or, add an additional condition and use the `OR` flag. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.example\.com [NC]
```

Comment: What i'm trying to do is to access my website via www.mydomain.ro, not www.mydomain.ro/public-dir-name and i think i have a .htaccess problem.

My structure is this:

Home(root dir)/my-project-dir(all laravel app files without public dir)
Home/public_html/some-dir-name(all public folder from laravel app)

In this moment, to access the website i need to go like this: www.mydomain.ro/some-dir-name.
I'm trying to get rid of /some-dir-name

Comment: And if i do this, my subdomains will work or all the URLs will point to www.mydomain.ro?

Comment: Just to make it clear....Do i need to edit the home/user/public_html/some-dir-name or do i need to create a .htaccess file in home/user/project-dir with your code in it?

Comment: It depends where your subdomains point to on the filesystem, but it is quite possible that this would catch all your subdomains as well. However, you can add an additional condition to rewrite just the domain(s) you want. I've updated my answer. You should only need to edit the `.htaccess` file in your document root (presumably your `public_html` directory). I assume you already have a `.htaccess` file in the Laravel root directory.

Comment: You can modify the _CondPattern_ (the second argument to the `RewriteCond` directive is a regular expression). I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you.I will try and return with a comment:)
One more thing.Should i delete the default htaccess or add your code after the default code ends?

Comment: That depends what the "default code" is. You probably want to put these directive _before_ any existing directives in the document root, otherwise they may not do anything.